# How to remove 'Parent Directory' link from root folder in Apache directory listing

Tags: .htaccess, directory, webserver, apache

How can I allow directory listing in Apache for a specific (root) folder and its subfolders, but without showing a link to parent of that root folder. When user is in a subfolder, the 'Parent Directory'link is displayed to navigate to its parent, but when user is at the root folder I need to remove/hide this 'Parent Directory' link so that user cannot move above that 'root' hierarchy.

Comment: Just not possible. You could write your own php script to do the directory listing. Don't see any other way. But I would not bother. The link shouldn't be there, but it's not like anything terrible will happen when you click it.

Comment: You are probably not asking the right question:  Regardless of the link, any user can still get to the parent by removing the last folder from the URL.  You need to ensure the server will not return anything on such URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue, and this was the first search result, so I thought I'd share my solution. I don't have access to httpd-configs in my case, so I went with a different approach.

Because I won't be maintaining the indexed directory tree, I needed a solution that could exist just in the index root without any specific knowledge of its sub-directories. However, it does use an absolute path to the index root, so if your parent folder structure changes a lot, it may not work for you.

What I came up with was using a CSS URL attribute selector to hide the "Parent Directory" link when it led to the parent of the index root. It leaves a blank row, but at least it's not as intimidating as the "403 FORBIDDEN" error a user gets if they click Parent Directory one too many times.

Theoretically, the fix should be as simple as adding one line to your index root's .htaccess file:

```
IndexHeadInsert "<style type=\"text/css\">a[href=\"/absolute/path/to/index/root/parent/\"] {display: none;}</style>"
```

However, it seems that simple solution doesn't work in IE because the default doctype of the html that Apache spits out is too old to use attribute selectors.

Instead, we have to surround Apache's generated code with our own doctype using the [HeaderName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername) and ReadmeName keywords in the htaccess file. I went with the HTML5 doctype, although there may be a more appropriate one that works.

.htaccess file:

```
Options +Indexes

IndexIgnore "_index_header.html" "_index_footer.html"

HeaderName "/absolute/path/to/root/index/_index_header.html"
ReadmeName "/absolute/path/to/root/index/_index_footer.html"

IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble
```

_index_header.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a[href="/absolute/path/to/index/root/parent/"] {display: none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
```

_index_footer.html file:

```
    </body>
</html>
```

(Note that the CSS selector is to the index root's parent)

Works in all of the latest browser versions I tested it on (FF, IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera), and also all the way back to IE 7.

Also, now that you went through all the trouble of creating those files, you might as well make your index more snazzy. The [apache doc on mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html) has a bunch of options you can use to tweak things, on top of what you can do with CSS.

Comment: The css approach seems to only hide the link (as you mention). You can use insert a `<script>` tag instead of a `<style>` and use javascript to hide the whole row. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31904749/1704773 and it's comments below.

Answer (score 36):

You can hide the "Parent Directory" link by adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
IndexIgnore ..
```

But this will hide it for every directory.

If you have access to the httpd-configs you could try to remove the directive from per-server context:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/(?!var/www/your-root/subfolder)">
...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

As long as there is no IndexIgnore directive in an higher folder it should work for you.

Comment: @itoctopus I agree.  It's simple and clean.  The accepted answer is a kludge.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is the following:

```
<Directory "/www"> Options +Indexes IndexIgnore .. _other </Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "^/www/download/.{1,}"> IndexIgnoreReset ON IndexIgnore _other </DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: This is a great option. Works perfectly. The solution will remove the link only in the /www folder but every sub folder within it will be ok. Essentially its almost like you can make your own top level directory visually.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're not asking the right question.

If your point is to prevent users from *accessing* the upper directory, removing the link won't solve anything for you since anybody can simply strip the last directory from the URL.

For example, if your subfolder is `/var/www/secret/hive/subfolder` and your `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www`, and you share link `http://your.example.com/secret/hive/subfolder`, anybody can still access `http://your.example.com/secret/` or `http://your.example.com/secret/hive` even without that "Parent folder" link.

What you could do is:

- Put "empty" index.html in each folder above "subfolder".  Apache will then offer that
  file instead of listing, so the users won't know what's in "secret" or "hive".
- Disable listing in each folder above "subfolder".  Apache will then refuse to show
  the listing, so the users won't know what's in  "secret" or "hive".

However, if users are somehow able to *guess* names of files, they could still assemble a valid URL like `http://your.example.com/secret/password.txt` and with enough luck (and/or attempts), they could still get to some non-public information.

What you **should** do is:

- set `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/secret/hive/subfolder`,
- or (better) keep DocumentRoot but move *everything that is not public* out of `/var/www`.

so `http://your.example.com/` will show only the public information and there's no (HTTP) way how users can even *ask* for anything above.

Answer (score 1):

There's a working trick to solve this issue, checking the url pathname via JQuery.
Just add this code at the top of your .htaccess file (obviously we can't separate paragraph lines here):

`IndexHeadInsert "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script>$(document).ready(function(){if(document.location.pathname.split('/').length<4){$('tr:nth-of-type(2)').hide();}});</script>"`

Note:

- you may need to change the pathname length value, in my site is "**4**" because my archive root starts in a secondary subdirectory (if yours starts in the main root, try different values e.g. "3" or "2", or simply check your location.pathname length before all).
- the "**tr:nth-of-type(2)**" css points to the second  record, that is the one supposed to manage the "PARENT DIRECTORY" we want to hide if the url location is our main root.

Have fun!

Comment: no need for jquery. `IndexHeadInsert "<script>if (document.location.pathname == '/') document.querySelector('tbody > tr:nth-child(3)').remove();</script>"` should work fine. For some reason my "parent directory" is the 3rd row (I have a header row and a separator before the directory listing starts). Change `'/'` to whatever pathname you want to hide the parent link for, eg. `'/builds/'` - it should automagically be hidden for a root pathname anyway.

Comment: I had to change your answer to this `IndexHeadInsert "<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {if (document.location.pathname == '/sub-folder/') document.querySelector('tbody > tr:nth-child(3)').remove();},false);</script>`  This forces the javascript to execute once the DOM is ready

Answer (score 0):

For more clarification...
Let we control this stuff from in directory .htaccess file, i.e .htaccess file that exist on the targeted directory. It may take the following configurations:

```
# STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
            IndexIgnore ".." #LOOK AT THIS LINE     
            IndexOptions FancyIndexing
            IndexOptions VersionSort
           # IndexOptions HTMLTable
            IndexOptions FoldersFirst
            IndexOptions IconsAreLinks
            IndexOptions IgnoreCase
           # IndexOptions SuppressDescription
            AddDescription "Last generated backup result" backuplog.txt
            IndexOptions SuppressHTMLPreamble
            IndexOptions XHTML
            IndexOptions IconWidth=32
            IndexOptions IconHeight=32
            IndexOptions NameWidth=*
            IndexOrderDefault Descending Name
            HeaderName /index-style/header.html
            ReadmeName /index-style/footer.html
        </ifModule>
```

For hide the parent directory link, `IndexIgnore` should be written as shown in the code above. The above snippet has been tested with Apache 2.4.18.

Comment: The [existing answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10348160/369434) already states this. But this does not resolve the problem, since this will also remove the "Parent Directory" link from all subdirectories as well, which is not what the OP is wanting.

Comment: @MrWhite We can workaround this limitation by adding a `.htaccess`  in every subfolder without `IndexIgnore`.